# How to retrieve complete chat from a Twitter chat?

Tags: chat, twitter

I was in a Twitter chat with a group on tweetchat.com but now when I search the for chat tag, only the last 20 messages or so show up. Is there a way to retrieve all of the chat, which is probably 200–300 messages?

I didn't see any "view more" buttons etc., but I thought maybe I should be using another website or service to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a "View Conversation" buttons on your own tweets which should enable you to view the whole conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter doesn’t have a chat function. What it has is “conversations,” which basically is a reply-to stream of tweets. What TweetChat does is it adds a specific hashtag to your tweets, so you can follow the stream of tweets that include it. So if you want to see all the tweets that include a particular hashtag, head to https://twitter.com/search-home and search for it. (Including the `#` symbol in front of it—e.g. `#myHashTag`.)